# Merge a linq expression from both db and in memory data

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework for querying data and I need to merge data already  in memory (including new record) with the ones in db.

For example:

> ```
> var linqdb = from d in context.Set<DEPARTMENT>()
>              join i in context.Set<INSTALLATION>() 
>              on d.INSTID equals i.INSTID
>              select new { d.DEPTNAME, i.INSTNAME };
>
> var linqm = from d in context.Set<DEPARTMENT>().Local
>             join i in context.Set<INSTALLATION>().Local 
>             on d.INSTID equals i.INSTID
>             select new { d.DEPTNAME, i.INSTNAME };
>
> var linqunion = linqm.Union(linqdb.AsEnumerable());
> ```

The difference is only the source where to execute the query: 
the first is database the second is in memory.
How I could achieve a result without having to rewrite the LINQ query 2 times?

Regards
Luigi

Comment: Encapsulate in a method that takes both source collections as IQueryable?

Comment: I want have a way to translate a base LINQ expression that can works on both source (db and local)